# Verb - question words database or api

Tags: грамматика, падежи

I'm writing an app for Russian language learners and I am looking for a database (as a csv file for example or an API) of Russian verbs and their associated cases? For instance something that can tell me the verb "дать" takes "что, кому" or "accusative, dative" or "винительный, дательный"?

I can't find anything online that will give me that information for every verb. Яндекс has a dictionary service and openrussian.org has a dictionary database as well, but I can't seem to find anywhere that has the correct cases for verbs.

Do anyone have any idea where I might be able to get my hands on something like that?

Comment: if all else fails you could knock up your own using [Д. Э. Розенталь "Управление в русском языке: Словарь-справочник"](http://padabum.com/x.php?id=49773) as a source

Comment: or using this [Бабенко Л.Г. — «Толковый словарь русских глаголов. Идеографическое описание Английские эквиваленты. Синонимы. Антонимы»](http://lib100.com/ru/tolkovyy_slovar-_hlaholov/pdf/)

Comment: also you may find "Словарь сочетаемости слов русского языка"

Comment: i checked "Словарь сочетаемости слов русского языка", it's useless for the intended purpose

Comment: the problem of this dictionary from practical perspective is that it covers not only verbs so one has to sift through to find required material, whereas in others one can go straight

Comment: try this http://www.solarix.ru/sql-dictionary-sdk.shtml

Comment: ....he would have troubles with multi-verbs like "есть" :-D

Comment: @permeakra if you make that an answer, I will be happy to mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

You may have not known, but in Russian language you can make a verb from almost every word, and people always come up with new ones. So if you are planning of making an if statement for every single verb in Russian language (that's what you want to do, and it's called hard coding), you are certainly going to fail. What you need is to find an algorithm or train an neural network (preferably second) for your task.